R programming debug
I am trying to understand the code written by my teammate. However, I couldn't understand few lines. Can you help me in explaining what these lines of code do?
ctrlv_sum_IBD is the data frame.
column_types<-as.vector(sapply(ctrlv_sum_IBD, class))
column_types<-gsub("character","text",column_types)


column_appended<-toString(unlist(lapply(seq_along(column), function(i)( paste(column[[i]], 
column_types[[i]])))))


Why don't you ask your teammate? It's literally part of their job to explain their code to you.

Then share (parts of) ctrlv_sum_IBD and column to ensure reproducibility of your question. Voted to close.

I presume this extracts the class of the columns of ctrlv_sum_IBD, changes any appearances of "character" to call them "text," (perhaps intended to be a more accessible term for users) and then outputs a string listing each of the columns and that (adjusted) class.

Looks like a mess to me. toString(paste(colnames(ctrlv_sum_IBD), gsub("character", "text", sapply(ctrlv_sum_IBD, class))))  should do it.


(ctrlv_sum_IBD <- data.frame(
  a="i am text",
  b=factor("im a factor"),
  x=1
))

column <- names(ctrlv_sum_IBD)

(column_types <- as.vector(sapply(ctrlv_sum_IBD, class)))
(column_types <- gsub("character", "text", column_types))


(column_appended <- toString(unlist(lapply(seq_along(column), function(i) {
  (paste(
    column[[i]],
    column_types[[i]]
  ))
}))))

"a text, b factor, x numeric"


thank you so much Nir Graham..! Excellent

Hi @Nir Graham, I understood the lines which you explained. However, the next line in the code snippet is quite confusing. Can you please the significance of "column_appended" in the below code.
                 sql_command<-paste("Create table ",SchemaName, ".", IBD_CategorySales_and_ContolVolume_table, " (",column_appended,");",sep="")


paste is a function for stitching together long text for smaller text elements. It seems clear that this code is about constructing sql commands. Do you understand SQL?
